# When is the best time to remove no-js classes from the html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I, like most devs, like to know when js is and isn't being used and style websites a little differently accordingly.

I then use this, almost immediately under the title to try and scrape the class off of the tag before the page is styled, rather than in a jQuery ready function to prevent the page from jumping.

```
<script>var a=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];a.className&&(a.className=a.className.replace(/no-js\s?/, ''));</script>
```

Is this, or is this not good practice and if not, where should it go. Sources to back up your answer please!

Consider page ready speeds, user experience and SEO.

Comment: What do you mean by "jumping"?

Comment: Isn't this what the noscript tag is for ?

Comment: Wrapping the html tag with noscript is not valid unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to use a no-js class when you can install a no-js stylesheet.

```
<link href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<noscript>
    <link href="/css/nojs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</noscript>
```

Doing it with javascript just seems out of place. you'll have an arbitrary line in your javascript that removes a class from an element for no reason important to said javascript. Not to mention the cost of rendering the no-js version then rending the js version due to removing the class after rendering has began.

Using a no-js stylesheet should improve (even if just slightly) the performance of the js version of your site, and gives you the freedom to move and change your script without having to worry about it affecting your no-js class removal because your js no longer has anything to do with it.

If you absolutely insist on doing this with javascript, i'd suggest doing it with inline javascript immediately after said element.

```
<body class="no-js">
<script>
    //document.body.className = "";
    document.body.classList.remove("no-js");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `<head>` is the best place to prevent the "flash of unstyled content". Even the popular [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) library [suggests this](http://modernizr.com/docs/):

> The reason we recommend placing Modernizr in the head is two-fold: the HTML5 Shiv (that enables HTML5 elements in IE) must execute before the `<body>`, and if you’re using any of the CSS classes that Modernizr adds, you’ll want to prevent a FOUC.